# SAM give access to Cognito

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, aws-serverless, serverless-application-model

I want to be able to call cognito functions through boto3 from my Lambda function in Python environment. What's the best way to give this type of access? I've done the following yaml but not sure if that's the best practice or I'm making the template longer.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  sam-app

  Sample SAM Template for sam-app

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello_world/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.7
      Policies:
       - AWSLambdaExecute # Managed Policy
       - Version: '2012-10-17' # Policy Document
         Statement:
           - Effect: Allow
             Action:
               - cognito-idp:ListUsers
             Resource: 'arn:aws:cognito-idp:us-east-2:****:*****'

      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get

Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/"
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: "Hello World Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn
  HelloWorldFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunctionRole.Arn
```

I'm talking about the "Policies", is my template up to the standards? or is there a shortcut I can take?

Comment: Did you update your template to use something else?  Or did you keep your policy as is?